# What is a proper antonym of "achievement"

Tags: nouns, antonyms

What word best describes the opposite of "achievement"?

It can have more than one interpretation:

- met achievement that is not desirable
- unmet desirable achievement

I'm interested in all you throw at me.

Thanks. (I'm not native speaker.)

(And *misachievement* doesn't really exist.)

Comment: You can use an online thesaurus to look for antonyms.

Comment: Some more context would be useful. This sounds like it could relate to a staff appraisal form??

Comment: Any votes for "non-achievement"?

Comment: Mitch: Antonyms sections is really great!

Answer (score 5):

[**Unaccomplished**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unaccomplished) [ˌʌnəˈkɒmplɪʃt]: not completed or done; unfinished.

**[Unfulfilled](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unfulfilled)** [ˌʌnfʊlˈfɪld]: not completed or achieved; unfulfilled ambitions

[**Unrealized**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unrealized) [ʌnˈrɪəˌlaɪzd] : not made real or actual; not resulting in accomplishment, as a task or aim: *unrealized ambitions*.

[**Debacle**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/debacle?show=0&t=1372204332) [dē-ˈbä-kəl]

- a : a great disaster
- b : a complete failure : fiasco

"After the debacle of his first novel, he had trouble getting a publisher for his next book."

Answer (score 3):

Failure:
An achievement is something that you have achieved. A failure is when you attempt something but are not successful.

Answer (score 2):

Demerit? When you do something and are awarded "negative" achievement. Kind of like the opposite of a gold star earned in a classroom.

Comment: This works best in my case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For "Unmet desirable achievement," I agree with @HellisHeat on  *failure*. An emerging internet usage is an *epic fail*.

For a "met achievement that is not desirable," perhaps one of these phrases might help:

- [Golden Fleece Award](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Fleece_Award), given by Senator William Proxmire, given
  for wasteful government spending.
- [Golden Raspberry Award](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_award), or a
  *razzie*, given for bad films.
- *dubious distinction*, as in "He had the dubious distinction of the highest Flesch–Kincaid grade level for
  any user manual."

There may be another dimension of "met goal that was accidentally achieved." A noun to describe this would be [serendipity](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/serendipity).

Comment: Thank you for including the stuff about "met achievement that is not desirable"! I have been looking for this information for days now.